# XML convert to HTML based on qualified results but position() doesn't work for my case

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML fragment like the following:

```
<OBRES>
<MODULE_RESULT>
    <U>http://www.example.com/test1.html/</U>
    <Title><b>Cancer</b> Test1 cancer</Title>
    <Field name="gsa:image:src">http://www.example.com/images/iamge1.jpg</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:card">summary</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:site">@TEST1SITE</Field>
</MODULE_RESULT>
<MODULE_RESULT>
    <U>http://www.example.com/test2.html/</U>
    <Title><b>Cancer</b> Test2 cancer</Title>
    <Field name="gsa:image:src">http://www.example.com/images/iamge2.jpg</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:card">summary</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:site">@TEST2SITE</Field>
</MODULE_RESULT>

<MODULE_RESULT>
    <U>http://www.example.com/test5.html</U>
    <Title>Article By Category  </Title>
    <Field name="viewport">width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0</Field>
    <Field name="robots"></Field>
    <Field name="title">Article By Category</Field>
    <Field name="description"></Field>
    <Field name="keywords"></Field>
    <Field name="language">en-US</Field>
    <Field name="application-name">UTSW Medicine</Field>
    <Field name="msapplication-task">name=Overview;   action-uri=/overview;   icon-uri=/favicon.ico</Field>
</MODULE_RESULT>

<MODULE_RESULT>
    <U>http://www.example.com/test3.html/</U>
    <Title><b>Cancer</b> Test3 cancer</Title>
    <Field name="gsa:image:src">http://www.example.com/images/iamge3.jpg</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:card">summary</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:site">@TEST3SITE</Field>
</MODULE_RESULT>
<MODULE_RESULT>
    <U>http://www.example.com/test4.html/</U>
    <Title><b>Cancer</b> Test4 cancer</Title>
    <Field name="gsa:image:src">http://www.example.com/images/iamge4.jpg</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:card">summary</Field>
    <Field name="twitter:site">@TEST4SITE</Field>
</MODULE_RESULT>
</OBRES
```

I would like to convert into HTML based on the following XSLT

```
  <xsl:if test="count(MODULE_RESULT)>0 ">
          <div class="onebox>
            <h5>My Stories</h5>
            <div>
            <xsl:for-each select="MODULE_RESULT[position()&lt;=3]">
                <xsl:variable name="gsa_image_src">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'gsa:image:src'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="twitter_card">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'twitter:card'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="twitter_site">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Field">
                        <xsl:if test="@name = 'twitter:site'">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$gsa_image_src != '' and $twitter_card != '' and $twitter_site != ''">
                    <p>
                <img>
                  <xsl:attribute name="src">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$gsa_image_src"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$twitter_card"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>                
                </img>
                    <span><xsl:value-of select="$twitter_card" /></span> 
                <span><xsl:value-of select="$twitter_site" /></span>     
                    </p>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </div>
      </xsl:if>
```

The qualified MODULE_RESULT will be those with gsa:image:src not empty and twitter:card is not empty and twitter:site is not empty. After conversion, I need to list maximum 3 of qualified items. This one doesn't work. My case has four qualified MODULE_RESULT and one disqualified MODULE_RESULT but only show two.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the expected result by changing the xsl:for-each as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(MODULE_RESULT[Field[@name='gsa:image:src']]
                                    [Field[@name='twitter:card']]
                                    [Field[@name='twitter:site']])[position() &lt;= 3]">
```

The result:

```
  <div class="onebox">
     <h5>My Stories</h5>
     <div>
        <p>
           <img src="http://www.example.com/images/iamge1.jpg" alt="summary"></img>
           <span>summary</span>
           <span>@TEST1SITE</span>
        </p>
        <p>
           <img src="http://www.example.com/images/iamge2.jpg" alt="summary"></img>
           <span>summary</span>
           <span>@TEST2SITE</span>
        </p>
        <p>
           <img src="http://www.example.com/images/iamge3.jpg" alt="summary"></img>
           <span>summary</span>
           <span>@TEST3SITE</span>
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works but it is possible that you check three fields are not empty directly from the statement:

Comment: from the statement: <xsl:for-each select="(MODULE_RESULT[Field[@name='gsa:image:src']]
                                    [Field[@name='twitter:card']]
                                    [Field[@name='twitter:site']])[position() &lt;= 3]">

Comment: @S.Chu The predicates ([...]) in xsl:for-each/select attribute expression are interpreted as combined by "and" logical operator. As a result this attribute selects only MODULE_RESULT elements that satisfies three fields are not empty. This should satisfy your requirement.